# Insert hex value in escape format (bytea)

Tags: postgresql-9.3, bytea

How to insert hex value like \x320000000d2f2100
in escape format into bytea field ?

bytea_output settings set to escape

Answer (score 3):

The `bytea_output` setting has nothing to do with how bytea is *interpreted by the server*, only how it's *sent to the client*.

Do you want to insert the literal string `\x320000000d2f2100` (as 7-bit ascii), i.e. producing the bytes `0x5c 0x78 0x33 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x64 0x32 0x66 0x32 0x31 0x30 0x30`?

If so, escape the backslash, as documented in the syntax for `escape` format bytea literals.

```
regress=> SELECT BYTEA '\\x320000000d2f2100';
                 bytea                  
----------------------------------------
 \x5c7833323030303030303064326632313030
(1 row)
```

Do you want to insert the bytes `0x32 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0d 0x2f 0x21 0x00`, i.e. the hex value? If so, *don't* escape the backslash. It doesn't matter what the setting of `bytea_output` is.

```
regress=> SELECT BYTEA '\x320000000d2f2100';
       bytea        
--------------------
 \x320000000d2f2100
(1 row)
```

Comment: I need the second option, already inserted (updated 1 row) like  set data=quote_literal('\x320000000d2f2100')::bytea                  The result stored in db is the same as SELECT BYTEA '\x320000000d2f2100' : 2\000\000\000\015/!\000 ,so sounds like it is ok. thanks!